# Programmatically accessing TFS history

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, tfs

I have a solution under TFS source control and had written some sample code using an external library that was deleted a few months ago. I am certain that the code was checked in before that class file was deleted.

I am able to manually browse to previous versions of even deleted files and copy old code but the number of check-ins is massive since then.

Is there a way to programmatically access TFS history using C# so I can automate the process of "Find in historic/deleted files"?

I know people have written scripts in PowerShell for TFS but I'd prefer to write a C# utility if it is possible. Any hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: May take a look at the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` namespace. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Looking into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shai Raiten's Blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/) is great for learning the TFS API.

For getting file history - read this post:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2014/09/10/tfs-api-part-55-source-control-get-history/